# Google App Engine Bulk download

Tags: python, google-app-engine, download, bulk

I was downloading data(more than 1 GB) from datastore using bulk download. Suddenly, my internet stopped working and download process stopped in middle. I want to resume from where it stopped. When I try, I get the following error

```
File "/Users/FYP/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py", line 156, in ValidateString
    (name, value, typename(value)))
BadArgumentError: kind should be a string; received 3 (a int):
[INFO    ] [WorkerThread-2] Backing off due to errors: 1.0 seconds
[INFO    ] An error occurred. Shutting down...
[ERROR   ] Error in WorkerThread-0: kind should be a string; received 3 (a int):
```

This is my code to download the data

```
appcfg.py download_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --batch_size=200 --filename=final80_2.csv 
--kind=TasksTime1 --url=http://abc.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --rps_limit=40 
--db_filename=bulkloader-progress-20110429.141103 --result_db_filename=bulkloader-results-20110429.141103
```

How to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Just re-run the same command. Per [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html):

> If the transfer is interrupted, you
>   can resume the transfer from where it
>   left off using the --db_filename=...
>   argument. The value is the name of the
>   progress file created by the tool,
>   which is either a name you provided
>   with the --db_filename argument when
>   you started the transfer, or a default
>   name that includes a timestamp. This
>   assumes you have sqlite3 installed,
>   and did not disable the progress file
>   with --db_filename=skip.

You specified a `db_filename` on the first execution, so if you re-run the command, it should find the existing file and pick up where it left off.

Comment: i ran the same command again, still getting the same error. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Might be a bug. You can try the patch posted here: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3581

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue:

```
Error in WorkerThread-0: kind should be a string; received 3 (a int)
```

Removing all *.sql3 and *.csv files stopped this error from occurring. Obviously, yes, the resuming is broken, but if you want to be able to bulk download again you'll have to disable it.

As a matter of course, we normally wrap the bulkloader commands in a function to clean these files beforehand.